# Как отловить изменение ItemsSource в WPF DataGrid после редактирования ячейки

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Для WPF DataGrid привязан источник данных ObservableCollection<>. Колонки заданы как обычные DataGridTextColumn. После редактирования ячейки, если нажать например Enter, изменяется свойство из соответствующего ряда, но обработчик события CollectionChanged коллекции-источника не вызывается. Как отловить момент, когда после изменения текста ячейки меняется свойство в связанном объекте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Событие `CollectionChanged` отправляется лишь при изменении *самой коллекции*, то есть, добавлении/удалении/замене *целых* элементов. При изменениях самих элементов `CollectionChanged` не отправляется.

Для отлова изменения *внутри* элемента вам нужно (при добавлении этого элемента) подписаться на событие `PropertyChanged`, если ваш тип данных элемента поддерживает интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Впрочем, `DataGrid` по идее делает это самостоятельно, вам не должно быть нужно об этом заботиться.

Если же ваш элемент *не имплементирует* `INotifyPropertyChanged`, то нормального метода отловить изменения внутри элемента нет. Поэтому объекты, используемые в качестве источника данных для UI-контролов, практически обязаны имплементировать `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Можно подумать о том, чтобы сделать для класса модели сделать класс Facade, в котором реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @Bulson: Угу, и назвать это фасад `VM` :-)